# Trouble with compiling in CLion

Tags: c++, c++11, clion

I have just begun using the newly released EAP build of CLion by JetBrains, and the whole thing runs on CMake. I wrote the CMake script correctly, I think, because all the libraries are included and no errors are thrown up on that front.

But the code uses the std::thread libraries, and I am getting errors on compilation as follows:

> std::thread has not been declared.

A whole host of related errors follow from here. I specified in CMakeList according to several stackoverflow posts to use C++ 11 compiler as follows:

> add_compile_options(-std=c++0x)

And I have included the `thread.h` header as well. This seems to be having no effect on compilation, and is happily frustrating me with the same damn errors over and over again.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Nope. Same problem again.

Comment: CLion only works on MinGW. MinGW doesn't support a lot of stuff like `std::thread` and `std::to_string`. Only Mingw-w64 does and that's not supported currently by CLion.

Comment: Oh, I see! Thank you very much! But is it possible to use boost::thread instead? Or perhaps change compiler to Cygwin instead?

Comment: Yeah, `boost::thread` will work.

Comment: Oh.pity CLion doesnt supply the boost libraries.

Comment: @Rapptz, when my gcc 4.8.2 with MinGWx32 didn't had std::thread, I thought it is problem of gcc version, not MinGW. Why do you think that was MinGW problem?

Comment: @gratefulguest, just build boost with your MinGW and it have to work.

Comment: @Arkady Because MinGWx32 refuses to support `std::thread` et al. Politics.

Comment: BTW, it should be `c++11` not `c++0x` now.

Comment: tried that. Threw up error of nonrecognition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible with MinGWx32. And MinGWx64 is not currently supported (http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-668). You can use Cygwin instead. Select it in Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Toolchain.

Answer (score 1):

"  CLion only works on MinGW. MinGW doesn't support a lot of stuff like std::thread and std::to_string. Only Mingw-w64 does and that's not supported currently by CLion. –  Rapptz Sep 12 at 10:45  "

This comment couldn't be further from the truth...

If you go to Jetbrains site and view the eap version info, or better yet go to their dev blog they address a lot of questions like this.